# Illustrator's Art Brush image that I made appears on its side and not upright which is the direction I gave it

Tags: adobe-illustrator

in Illustrator, I made a character that stands upright appearing to wave its hand. I then made it into an art brush with the following criteria's; Scale proportionately, Direction: Up and Colorization: Tint. It worked perfectly except I forgot to put a fill in one of the sections of the character, so I re-did the art brush following the same criteria (specifically "Direction: Up") and now it appears on its side (Direction: Left) when I make a path that goes upwards.

Does anyone know why it's doing that and how can I stop it. I know within the art brush panel I can change the direction, the vertical & horizontal flip etc. but that doesn't help it from happening again. I am hoping to find out the reason it happens so I can avoid it from occurring again.

thank you so much.

[image]

Comment: Would need to see the brush settings. A vertical brush should remain vertical if a path is vertical.

Comment: I just added a screen shot to the original question. Thank you

Comment: Thanks. And you're drawing a vertical path? For the brush to appear as it does in the preview you **must** draw a *vertical* path. I can't replicate this issue. Based on your artboard, I'd *guess* that the path is horizontal. If you *want* the brush path to follow the vertical nature of the artwork, then merely toggle the directional options for the bush until the green arrow matches what you want.

Comment: This issue may be due to *how* you "redid everything". If you merely replaced the existing brush artwork, as opposed to creating an entirely new brush, some settings remnants may have remained, causing the rotation issue.

Comment: Sorry, the drawing on the artboard is not a vertical path, it is the artwork that I attempted to make the art brush from. The preview in the art brush panel is the result I am getting once I press ok and try to make a vertical path, it is displayed horizontally.

Comment: Just change the green arrow in the brush settings to follow the path you want. Your preview is exactly how the brush will be applied.. the green arrow indicates the drawn path direction. The fact that the *artwork* in the brush preview is horizontal doesn't *really* matter that much.. it's the green arrow and how it relates to that artwork which matters.

Comment: I think I figured out the issue, I can't be certain but it makes the most sense. I try to make a video to better communicate my issue, but in doing so I cleaned up my layers, removed locked and invisible paths out of the layers that were not relevant. Upon removing them, I selected the artwork layer and created an new Art Brush, I chose; Scale proportionately, Direction: arrow Up and Colorization: Tint, (same as I did the 1st time) then pressed ok. I made an upward vertical path and it displayed correctly. I believe the issues was the hidden & locked paths in the layer. I will test further.

Comment: Locked objects shouldn't matter (they wouldn't be included when dragging to the brush panel). But *hidden* objects, if included when creating the brush, can certainly create different brush artwork.

Comment: I think you're correct, I can't seem to reconstruct the issue. I do recall locked objects still being engaged when I clicked the master layer, which was weird but they did not appear in the brush. Perhaps I have a bug, but in the future I will be sure to keep my layers as simple as possible, only what is relevant. I am only 4 weeks in with illustrator so I save paths as references until I have it all figured out. That might be the error of my ways. Thanks so much. Really appreciate it and if I find a definitive reason. I will let you know. Cheers